# z-index of nested span within jquery draggable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, z-index, draggable

I have a draggable div and nested within that div I have another div that is resizable.

The div's are created on the fly.

To make matters slighty more complicated, I then have a span within the resizable div, with some text in.

The problem I have is, I want the text to be highlightable, but the draggable element of the parent div is not allowing this.

If I change the span to a text area all is good, but a textarea will not work for what I want.

I have tried to set the z-index of the span to higher than the div's(z-index:2000;) but no joy, the draggale element is still to the forefront.

any ideas?

heres my div

```
var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
newdiv.setAttribute('id', id);
newdiv.setAttribute('class', 'dragbox');
newdiv.setAttribute('iterate',i);   
newdiv.style.position = "absolute";
newdiv.style.top = top+"px";
newdiv.style.left = left+"px";
newdiv.style.cursor='move';
newdiv.style.zIndex=zindex;
newdiv.innerHTML = "<br><div id='div"+i +"' style='zindex:1;'><span id='span"+i+"' style='z-index:2000;'>"+content+"</span></div></div>";
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to `stopPropagation()` of the click event in the `span`. Do you have a working example in a jsfiddle?

Comment: Try to give <span id='span"+i+"' style='z-index:2000;position: absolute'>

Comment: I already have a stopPropagation() when i click on a button called 'edit text', I am trying to make a simple rich text editor for the content of the span. unfortunatley I cannot put together a jsfiddle as the page is constructed on the fly from a  mySQL db with php

Comment: Have you tried using `position: absolute;` on your span? It can sometimes work in combination with z-index when z-index alone doesn't.

Comment: @Calvin z-index alone doesn't work at all. It needs positioning which is must.

Comment: i see one typo zindex:1;

Comment: i see a potential second typo when closing the divs in the last line should be only one </div>

Comment: Rory heres a js fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/ARc7G/25/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry if I missunderstand but you are trying to give a higher z-index to a div than its parent div? , if so is not going to work.

as what I see in your code the z-index:2000 is inside z-index:1 so indeed for the browser is just z-index:1

EDIT

did you try with

```
event.preventDefault();
```

inside the mousedown mousemove and mouseup events?

Comment: ok thanks, it was my first attempt at getting the content of the span, editable.  Do you have any ideas as to how I can make the inner span editable? I can get a alert working when I click on the content of the span by using   var spanclick=document.getElementById('span'+i);
 spanclick.onclick=function(e){
  alert("hello world");
 }  but am unable to make the content highlightable